# libxml2 - remove child, but not grandchildren

Tags: html, c, libxml2

I'm using libxml2 to parse HTML. I want to remove certain formatting tags like `<center>`, while keeping their content (for example, a link).

This means I'll have to remove certain child nodes from my `xmlNodeSet`, but keep that node's children.

Right now, I got this code:

```
xmlNodePtr parentNode = nodes->nodeTab[i];

if (parentNode != NULL) {
    xmlNodePtr child = parentNode->children;
    xmlNodePtr parentNextSibling = parentNode->next;
    xmlNodePtr grandParent = NULL;

    while (child) {
        xmlUnlinkNode(child);
        if (parentNextSibling != NULL) {
            xmlAddPrevSibling(parentNextSibling, child);
        }
        else {
            if (grandParent == NULL)
                grandParent = parentNode->parent;
            xmlAddChild(grandParent, child);
        }

        child = child->next;
    }

    xmlUnlinkNode(parentNode);
    xmlFree(parentNode);
}
```

The code does add the child to the document, but it also deletes the node I was adding it as a sibling to. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not saving off the child->next pointer before you cut it out of the tree.  As soon as you unlink a node, it isn't part of the tree, so child->next becomes NULL.  Then, after you reinsert it into the tree (before parentNode->next), the child->next pointer now points to what was previously parentNode->next, so the next time through the loop, you delete parentNode->next.  Things can only go downhill from there.  :-)